# BCE0044: expecting EOF, found 'Player'

Tags: unity-game-engine

in this frame: local; <----- this solution is very important to my game (use unity but the errors ignore [error: BCE0044: expecting EOF, found 'Player'. don't ignore])

```
#pragma strict

if (game(GetService("RunService")(IsClient())) (then (error("Script must be server-side in order to work; use h/ and not hl/")))) end;
local; Player,game,owner = owner,game
local RealPlayer = Player
```

Comment: Unity is c#. That’s not looking c# like

Comment: this is not unity 2021-2022, is unity 5.5.6

Comment: It also does not look like unityscript.

Comment: This code appears to be a mismash of lua (specifically, code that might be used in roblox) and unityscript. So, it should come as no surprise unity 5.5.6 is having trouble interpreting it as unityscript. What is supposed to be the outcome of this code? Also, is there a particular reason you aren't using a modern version of unity?

Comment: Unity 5 is rediculously old.